# Where to place message and log events using PoEAA

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop

Currently, I have a structure like this:

`Domain Model <---> Data Mapper ---> Database`

Say I add a child 'file' object to a 'project' object. I want to automatically create a child 'note' object for that project signifying the update. Right now, the creation of this note is handled by the 'project file mapper' -- within the 'uploadFile' method, a new note is instantiated and populated, and a call is made to the 'note mapper' to save that note. The project invokes the note mapper when asked for its children notes, and so on with files.

Or say I delete a 'project' object -- I want to delete the children notes and files as well, so within the 'projectMapper' method 'deleteProject', a call is made to both 'projectNoteMapper' and 'projectFileMapper' to handle deleting those files.

There are other instances I am beginning to encounter now, especially since implementing a private messaging system. I want users to be able to subscribe to projects and tickets and receive messages about updates. I also want to implement deep logging of user action (including storing of serialized objects for tab-keeping.)

I understand that the way I have been doing things does not conform to the 'single responsibility principle' -- after all, the purpose of a mapper should only be to map information between data sources and their respective objects, right? My question is this -- what is the next 'layer' I should be implementing, what am I missing? I have read about 'Repository' and 'Service'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem, then i think might help t clear it up:

> DataMappers are not representation of, nor corresponding to single table in database.

In you case with projects, it would make a lot of sense for `$projectMapper->remove( $project )` to delete, not just the project itself, but the all the associated items in DB. There is nothing wrong with DataMapper making more then one query. You just need to implement the accompanying setup for error reporting, to know when/if something went wrong.

And yes, this too violates SRP in some aspects ( but only if you view each change in DB as a separate reason for modifying the DataMapper class ).

As for which is the next logical step for evolving Model layer : you will find this [PoEEE entry](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) relevant. Just keep in ming that `Service layer` is not just an API on top DataMappers and Domain Object. It also contains *services*, that are somewhat independent from rest of module. Like mail sender(s) and authentication.

Also, to clear this up:

> Model is not a class, but a layer, which contains both Domain Objects <sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_object)</sup> <sup>[[2]](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject)</sup> and DataMappers.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

When it comes to the mappers for Projects and Projectfiles, each uses multiple 'resources' -- that is multiple tables, or in the case of the projectfiles, system directories as well as database tables. For that reason (the significant difference between the two objects), I feel that they both deserve their own mapper. The issue is then coordinating this...

...and as with the link you posted (I have the book as well) it seems the service layer is just for that. I had already begun implementing the pattern after posting this question and it has been good. Thank you